# Why ng-class-even required extra quotes

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-class-even

I am working on angularJS where my codes are fine but i am stuck at one place where i cant find why extra quotes are required in `ng-class-even` directive.

In this line `<tr ng-repeat="x in records" ng-class-even='"striped"'>` why striped is written like this `"'striped'"` instead of this `"striped"`

```css
.striped {
    color:white;
    background-color:black;
}
```

```html
<body ng-app="myApp">
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>

<table ng-controller="myCtrl">
<tr ng-repeat="x in records" ng-class-even="'striped'">
  <td>{{x.Name}}</td>
  <td>{{x.Country}}</td>  
</tr>
</table>

<script>
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
  $scope.records = [
    {
      "Name" : "Alfreds Futterkiste",
      "Country" : "Germany"
    },
    {
      "Name" : "Berglunds snabbköp",
      "Country" : "Sweden"
    },
    {
      "Name" : "Centro comercial Moctezuma",
      "Country" : "Mexico"
    },
    {
      "Name" : "Ernst Handel",
      "Country" : "Austria"
    }
  ]
});
</script>

</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because `ng-class-even` allows to give a [expression](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClassEven). 
In your question you says:

> n this line  why striped is written like this "'striped'" instead of this "striped"

if you will try be do this, Angular thinks that `striped` is a variable attached in the `$scope`. So using `'striped'` tells to angular that the expression that you passed to the directive is a **string value**

Comment: but why only for `ng-class-even` or `ng-class-odd` and not in `ng-` class`

Comment: @GauravAggarwal And for ngClassOdd the same. ngClass has different purpose and notation. Did you even read documentation, would (probably) solve many of your questions.

Comment: @GauravAggarwal I suggest to check official documentation first, it's often enough.

Answer (score 3):

> [**`ng-class-even`**](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClassEven) expects an [`expression`](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression) but you are willing to assign a hard coded string and strings are wrapped in `quotes` to be valid `token` or else `angular` parser will look for `model-name` having name as `striped`

Answer (score 1):

beacuse ng-class-even and odd both requires expression 
and you need String so you have to write String because you need hard coded string 
here is documentation for ng-class-even

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClassEven

you can see very good example at there